# Merging and training Theano autoencoders

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, theano, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm trying to use Theano's autoencoders to discover context-specific features from two different types of data.

The first type has 13 features and the second one has 60.

```
    n_ins=[13,60], 
    n_hiddens=[20, 20, 20],
```

Both have their own independent stack of autoencoders.

I merge the outputs of the topmost layers and feed these into a regression layer for supervised training.

```
self.logLayer = LogisticRegression(
        input=(self.sigmoid_layers[0][-1].output+self.sigmoid_layers[1][-1].output),
        n_in=self.n_modes*n_hiddens[-1],
        n_out=n_outs
    )
```

Pre-training for each context seems to work correctly, however I hit a snag during finetuning using the standard training function in the tutorials.

```
     train_fn = theano.function(
        inputs=[index],
        outputs=self.finetune_cost,
        updates=updates,
        givens={
            self.x: train_set_x[
                index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size
            ],
            self.y: train_set_y[
                index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size
            ]
        },
        name='train'
    )
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: dimension mismatch in args to gemm (5,73)x(13,20)->(5,20)
Apply node that caused the error: GpuDot22(GpuSubtensor{int64:int64:}.0, W)
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(5, 73), (13, 20)]
Inputs strides: [(73, 1), (20, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

I believe this has something to do with how the Theano nodes are processed during training. Seems like the training batch (5, 73), is being applied straight into the output nodes separately starting with the 1st context (13, 20).

Comment: So the autoencoder for the first input has input and encoder layer sizes 13, 20, 20, 20? And the autoencoder for the second input has input and encoder layer sizes 60, 20, 20, 20? i.e. the inner-most encoder layer has size 20 for both inputs? If so, shouldn't the regression layer have input size 40?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes that's pretty much the gist of it. And yes, the regression layer actually has 40 input nodes. The problem I'm having is with the fine-tuning phase. Basically, the pretraining works since I can address each input as a separate structure. However, for fine-tuning everything is taken as one structure. So, the whole input training data (size 73) is being fed into each input autoencoder (size 13 and 60) separately, leading to an exception when evaluating the first input (I think).